# Azure Application Gateway - Backend only works with port 80

Tags: azure-application-gateway

The backend application is a tomcat application running on port 8080. This application is running on my on-premise server. I'm able to access the application from the internet.I tested with a default tomcat application. http://:8080/

I configured the Azure Gateway HTTP setting to 8080, however i got timeout from Health probe.
It works fine if the port is 80. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with various port numbers. Apparently, only 8080 doesn't work. My ISP might have blocked it. :(